# Unknown config option "stream_tls" on motion 4.1.1

Tags: motion

I want to use `stream_tls` option as [this link](https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html#stream_tls) which tells:

> This option specifies whether to enable SSL/TLS for the stream port.
>   For some distributions the library that Motion uses may not have been
>   compiled with SSL/TLS support. In this situation Motion can not
>   support SSL/TLS connections. Whether SSL/TLS can be supported will be
>   reported in the log. In addition to selecting this option, a
>   webcontrol_cert and webcontrol_key file must also be specified.

When I add `stream_tls`, `webcontrol_tls`, `webcontrol_key` and `webcontrol_cert`, it gives me these logs:

```
[3626632:motion] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "stream_tls"
[3626632:motion] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "webcontrol_tls"
[3626632:motion] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "webcontrol_key"
[3626632:motion] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "webcontrol_cert"
```

I changed the configuration file `/etc/motion/motion.conf` and these lines:

```
stream_tls on

webcontrol_tls on
webcontrol_key /etc/motion/motion.key
webcontrol_cert /etc/motion/motion.crt
```

In addition, I created `/etc/motion/motion.key` and `/etc/motion/motion.crt` by the following procedure:

```
openssl genrsa -out /etc/motion/motion.key 4096
openssl req -new -key /etc/motion/motion.key -out /etc/motion/motion.crt
```

My objective is to make `motion` stream web page secure (`https`). I don't know why it's happening. I'm sure the problem is not with `.key` and `.crt` file because if I just add `stream_tls on`, it gives the same error for this option.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What version are you using? `stream_tls` was a new option in 4.2

Comment: @user1794469 Ahan, ok. I'll try another version.